# To test whether a coin is fair, Jane tossed it X times and observed that all outcomes were heads

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

If the p-value is greater than 0.05, what are the possible values of X?

(i) 4
(ii) 5
(iii) 6

Possible MCQ options:
(a) (i) only
(b) (i) and (ii) only.
(c) (i), (ii) and (iii).
(d)None of the above, X must be greater than 7

The answer is (a). Why is this so? How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer because it isn't specified whether the test is 1-tailed or 2-tailed. (Based on the supposed correct answer, the question must be assuming that the test was 1-tailed.)

Comment: For a one-sided test: Using R as a calculator, code `round(.5^(4:10) ,3)` returns P-values $0.062,0.031,0.016,0.008,$ $0.004,0.002,0.001,$ which correspond to $4,5,6,…$ tosses. For a 2-sided test, you need to double these P-values. // Yet another poorly written multiple choice question. No wonder you're puzzled.

Comment: It’s homework, I wouldn’t be overthinking the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This comment is for the future, not for your immediate frequentist statistics-laden question.  To obtain direct evidence for fairness of a coin you need to define the state of prior knowledge and to define fairness, e.g, the probability of heads $\theta$ being between 0.49 and 0.51.  Then acquire a lot of data and compute the Bayesian posterior probability that $\theta \in [0.49, 0.51]$.

The state of prior knowledge considers such things as the following:

- Was the coin selected at random from a bag of coins?  If so how was the bag selected?
- If the coin was intentionally made to be unfair, would the person who did this be crafty enough to avoid detection by not making $\theta$ to be outside the interval $[0.4, 0.6]$?  If so the prior distribution might be uniform on $[0.4, 0.6]$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the problem does not provide
enough information, I will show four
relevant *exact binomial tests* in R.

For such small numbers of tosses, I would not
use normal approximations.

---

**Right-sided alternative.**

Four tosses. right-sided $(H_0: p=.5$ against: $H_a: p > .5).$ Getting four Heads in four tosses does not quite
lead to rejection at the 5% level.

```
binom.test(4, 4, alt="greater")

        Exact binomial test

data:  4 and 4
number of successes = 4, number of trials = 4, 
  p-value = 0.0625
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4728708 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                     1
```

Five Heads out of five tosses does lead to rejection
at the 5% level, against the right-sided alternative.

```
binom.test(5, 5, alt="greater")$p.value
[1] 0.03125
```

---

**Two-sided alternative.**

Five tosses. two-sided $(H_0: p=.5$ against: $H_a: p \ne .5).$ Five Heads do not quite
lead to rejection at the 5% level.

```
binom.test(5, 5, alt="two")

        Exact binomial test

data:  5 and 5
number of successes = 5, number of trials = 5,
 p-value = 0.0625
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4781762 1.0000000
 sample estimates:
                 1
```

Getting six Heads in six tosses does lead to rejection at
the 5% level.

```
binom.test(6, 6, alt="two")$p.val
[1] 0.03125
```